# replace any non-ascii character in a string in java

Tags: java, regex, unicode

How would one convert `-lrb-300-rrb-┬á922-6590` to `-lrb-300-rrb- 922-6590` in java?

Have tried the following:

```
t.lemma = lemma.replaceAll("\\p{C}", " ");
t.lemma = lemma.replaceAll("[\u0000-\u001f]", " ");
```

Am probably missing something conceptual. Will appreciate any pointers to the solution.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "unicode"?  Any non-ascii?

Comment: i assumed those embedded special characters to be unicode...

Comment: and what do you mean by the word "unicode"?  According to the [standard definition](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode) all characters in that string are in unicode, not just "┬á".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the next:

#### `str = str.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", " ");`

By the way, `\p{ASCII}` is all ASCII: `[\x00-\x7F]`.

In ahother hand, you need to use a constant of `Pattern` for avoid recompiled the expression every time.

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("[^\\p{ASCII}]");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "-lrb-300-rrb-┬á922-6590";
    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceAll(" ")
    );  // prints "-lrb-300-rrb- 922-6590"
}
```

See also:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: why is [^\p{ASCII}]+ the preferred choice to [^\x20-\x7E]+?

Comment: It is a category already included in Java, you can see them in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to keep `a-zA-Z0-9` and punctuation characters, you could do:

```
t.lemma = lemma.replaceAll("[^\\p{Punct}\\w]", " "));
```

Comment: How about `t.lemma = lemma.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");` ?

Comment: That works too in this case but it includes more characters. I'm not sure what the OP wants.